# String not recognized as valid datetime with a List only containing months

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List of months of type "String".
I am trying to parse these into a DateTime object so I can sort/order the months by current month

```
List<String> test = new List<String>(Model.Attributes.Select(p => p.Title).ToList());
        var sortedMonths = test;
            sortedMonths = sortedMonths
            .Select(x => new { Name = x, Sort = DateTime.ParseExact(x.ToString(), "MMMM", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) })
            .OrderBy(x => x.Sort.Month)
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();
```

I am filling the List test and after debugging it shows it is filled with the months. However I keep getting an error when I try to parse them. I've tried to manually input a string month in the place of "x" to know for sure if the format works, and it does. I can't figure this out...

EDIT: I've also already tried manually setting the CurrentCulture.

Comment: What does `test` contain exactly? Month numbers or names?

Comment: It contains names, sorry for the confusion, i.e.: "Januari", "Februari" etc."

Comment: What is the value of `CurrentCulture` in your system?

Comment: Rather than try and parse it to names, then a date, and sort it, why not just make the months have preceeding 0's for shorts, and just sort by number.

Comment: As far as I can test it on my culture, that code works. Check if you have really valid months' names for the current culture

Comment: Can you tell which month name exactly failed? Or do all of them fail? These two months work successfully with culture nl-NL

Comment: Yes, I'am with Steve that code work well! Check for names of month

Comment: Apparently someone recently changed a query and mixed Dutch and English month names... I'm re-editing this to change it all to Dutch and  trying it agian!

Answer (score 0):

Due to someone here editing the query and mixing Dutch with English month names the code gave errors. The code was complete and works as intended now after re-editing the query to give only Dutch names. Thank you all!